# How to setup AD client certificate for a workgroup account to be used for authentication on a local IIS server website?

Tags: active-directory, iis, window-server-2019

I have two Windows Server 2019 virtual machines, one has Active Directory setup and Active Directory Certification Auhtority, the other one is a Workgroup server. The workgroup server has IIS installed on it an an application deployed. What I want is for the local user that visits the website to be require a valid certificate from Active Directory.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/askds/enabling-cep-and-ces-for-enrolling-non-domain-joined-computers-for-certificates

This is the closest thing I found, but I get a server or adress name could not be resolved when I try to create an enrollment policy on the client computer. I did everything like on the article, except installed a Certification Authority prior on the AD server and replaced the domain in the article with my domain name.

How can I achieve local client certificate authentication through Active directory on a website on IIS?

Comment: Why not join the IIS server to the domain as a member?

Comment: @Tommiie it's for school and the computer must be in workgroup for the purpose of the project

Comment: I vote to close for two reasons: (1) this website is for IT systems in a business environment, not school projects, and (2) your question does not present a clear problem statement. Share you configuration and what you tried, and show exactly what is wrong with the setup, i.e. show the output of logs and troubleshooting steps you took.